# Iterate over a record in BQ to fetch specific content

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have a record where there're multiple comment made by users and I want to fetch all of them. Record looks like:

[image]

The use case here is to fetch only the comment part.
I'm able to fetch the comments successfully if there's only one. But in case of multiples, it doesn't work.
`SELECT approver_comments_txt as f0, IF( CONTAINS_SUBSTR(TRIM(approver_comments_txt), ']'), IF(SUBSTR(TRIM(approver_comments_txt),(STRPOS(TRIM(approver_comments_txt),']') + 1),LENGTH(TRIM(approver_comments_txt))) != '', SUBSTR(TRIM(approver_comments_txt),(STRPOS(TRIM(trim(approver_comments_txt)),']') + 1),LENGTH(TRIM(approver_comments_txt))), NULL), TRIM(approver_comments_txt) ) as f1 FROM tbl_name`

please let me know if there's a feasible way to do so. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is distinct keyword a requirement for your query ? it seems to be working fine without it when I tested it.

Comment: No, I keep that for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the distinct to capture multiple comment capture in my testing, Please see result:

```
WITH
  cte AS (
  SELECT
    'campaign1[asd]a' AS approver_comments_txt,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'campaign2[aaaa]comment here' AS approver_comments_txt,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'campaign2[1231]' AS approver_comments_txt,
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    'campaign2' AS approver_comments_txt )
SELECT
  approver_comments_txt AS f0,
IF
  ( CONTAINS_SUBSTR(TRIM(approver_comments_txt), ']'),
  IF
    (SUBSTR(TRIM(approver_comments_txt),(STRPOS(TRIM(approver_comments_txt),']') + 1),LENGTH(TRIM(approver_comments_txt))) != '', SUBSTR(TRIM(approver_comments_txt),(STRPOS(TRIM(trim(approver_comments_txt)),']') + 1),LENGTH(TRIM(approver_comments_txt))), NULL), TRIM(approver_comments_txt) ) AS f1
FROM
  cte
```

[image]

Comment: No need for repeating `AS approver_comments_txt` after the first select. BR

Comment: It doesn't work when there're multiple comments in a single record. Like the very first record in attached snap.